# SLURM: Run two MPI jobs with different settings on same set of nodes

Tags: mpi, slurm, sbatch, intel-mpi

I have a slurm batch script, and I'm running Intel MPI.

I want to run two different MPI codes on the same set of nodes with different process placement configurations.

I'm running two MPI codes, one with -np = 8 and the other with -np = 2. For the -np=8 case, I want to place ranks [0, 1, 2, 3] from the first mpiexec on node0 and ranks [4, 5, 6, 7] from the second mpiexec on node1.

For the -np=2 case, I want to place rank [0] on node0 and rank [1] on node1.

I've tried -ppn, -perhost, I_MPI_PERHOST, all the options available [here, Intel process placement](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/controlling-process-placement-with-the-intel-mpi-library.html) but none of them are working.

My scripts are directly inheriting options from SBATCH instead of local settings. Please don't suggest srun; there's some issue with mpi and srun. I'm unable to run mpi with srun on multiple nodes (PMI error); mpiexec directly works on multiple nodes.

Is there any way I can achieve the above task? Here's the SBATCH script I'm currently using.

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -p small
#SBATCH -N 2
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00
#SBATCH --error=err.out
#SBATCH --output=out.out
#SBATCH --ntasks=10

module load compiler/intel/2018.2.199
module load apps/ucx/ucx_1.13.1

source /opt/ohpc/pub/apps/intel/2018_2/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpivars.sh intel64
export I_MPI_FALLBACK=disable

#--> First mpiexec
mpiexec.hydra -n 8 ./hello.out & 

#--> Second mpiexe
mpiexec.hydra -n 2 ./world.out & 

wait
```

Here my first mpiexec runs ranks [0,1,2,3,4] on node0 and [5,6,7] on node1
where as my second mpiexec runs ranks [0,1] on node 0.

I want my first mpiexec to run ranks [0,1,2,3] on node0 and ranks [4,5,6,7] on node1
I want my second mpiexec to run rank [0] on node0 and rank [1] on node1

I can't use srun I can only use mpiexec

Is there any way I can set local settings to each mpiexec?
Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: what about `mpirun -np 8 -ppn 4 ...` and `mpirun -np 2 -ppn 2 ...`?

Comment: -ppn is not working, its running all the processes on a single node.

Comment: fwiw, it works for me with Intel MPI 2021.7

Comment: You think it might be some issue with my MPICH implementation?

Comment: are you using MPICH or Intel MPI?

Comment: Sorry yeah, Intel MPI, the module loaded in my code intel/2018.2.199

Comment: since this is a pretty old version, I suggest you try a recent one. I am very puzzled the `-ppn` option is not working as advertised though.

Comment: Yes, the issue was indeed with the MPI version. I tried with the latest 2021 version, and it worked. Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the version of Intel MPI.

Using the latest version of Intel MPI fixed the issue.

I credit [Gilles Gouaillardet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8062491/gilles-gouaillardet) for the solution.
Please refer to the comments section for the discussion.